# re-enter password for specific pages after user login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

my app is developed in codeigniter. What I am looking to do is to prompt the user to re-enter the password in order to access certain sections like edit profile, settings etc.

My question is that if the user has signed up through facebook or twitter, how would I implement this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: err... by reading manuals? examples? tutorials perhaps?

Comment: I think I recognize the problem. If you already are authorised through Oauth2 (facebook, twitter..) and you do another request to the oauth service, it will not ask you to fill out your credentials again. As far as I know, there is no way to force the oauth-service to ask for the credentials again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/

> **Re-Authentication**
>   This when your app confirms a person's identity after checking previously. With Facebook Login, your app asks a person to re-enter their Facebook password at any time. You can use this to prevent cases where a user leaves a device logged in or where a third party hijacks someone's session with your app.

(The wording is a little off, but that’s a direct quote from the FB docs.)

By adding the parameter `auth_type=reauthenticate` to your login dialog call, you can force users to re-enter their password before procedding.